# Redirecting mobile devices to another page best practise

Tags: performance, php

I am redirecting mobile devices from the root `index.php` to `mobile.php` file. I only allow access to `mobile.php` file only when that if statement is true.

This is how I do it:

1. Detect Devices and store them into variables
2. If a mobile device (see variables) accesses the web application redirect to `mobile.php`
3. In `mobile.php` check again the same thing and redirect back to `index.php` if the device is not a mobile device.

   > Is this a good practice to redirect mobile devices to another file?

> Is there any tool to check my script from false positives?

**index.php**

```
    <?php #detecting mobile devices
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
    $ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

    if($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $ipad == true) 
{   
 header('Location: mobile.php');
 exit;
}
    ?>
```

**mobile.php**

```
<?php #detecting mobile devices
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");


if($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $ipad == true) 
{  
//do nothing
} 
else{ #device not one of the variables return to root file
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using some library for mobile device detection, like [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/). Your script will improperly detect many devices - this will be a big problem if you fill force redirection to mobile/desktop version of website based on false-positives.

> Is this a good practise to redirect mobile devices to another file?

It is a bad idea to force it. You should allow to choose which version (mobile or desktop) user wants to browse. So you may redirect him on first visit, but allow to switch between versions at any time.

Comment: Is there any online tool to check my website for false positives?

Comment: @csandreas1 I don't know any, but since you're only testing string from user agent, you may use data from unit tests of Mobile-Detect package and write own unit tests for this: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/tests/ualist.json

Answer (score 3):

The global task of mobile detection aside, just in regard of the current implementation.

Every time you see a duplicated code, there is a room for the improvement.

```
$mobile = false;
$mob_agents = ["iPhone","Android","webOS","BlackBerry","iPod","iPad"];
foreach ($mob_agents as $marker) {
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $marker) !== FALSE) {
    $mobile = true;
    break;
}
```

now you can use a `$mobile` variable to test whether it's a movile client or not

A more sophisticated version would involve basic regular expressions- something like this:

```
$pattern = "/iPhone|Android|webOS|BlackBerry|iPod|iPad/";
$mobile = preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: i did not get what you improved from my code, can you explain?

Comment: Does my answer give an ample explanation? If not, let me know what else you don't get.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a good practise to redirect mobile devices to another file securely?

If we're talking about security, we should first ask: what are we really trying to achieve?

Why do you want to disallow direct access to `mobile.php`? If one is on a mobile device, why shouldn't he be allowed to directly go there?

What kind of security problems are you trying to prevent by not allowing such direct access?

Seems to me that it's more of an inconvenience for the user.

> Is this a good practise to redirect mobile devices to another file?

In general, I would say: **no**, just serve the same page for all kinds of devices, regardless of mobile or not.

Perhaps though you have some sort of reason **why** you want to serve one kind of page to to mobile users. Without knowing that, however, I can't really assess whether your solution is good or bad.

Comment: your answer did not answer anything on my question, you are just asking. I just don't want users to see that file, only people from mobile device should

Comment: you are true about security i deleted that

Comment: Added reply to your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The code in [Your Common Sense's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/192930/120114) is a good improvement over the original code, for multiple reasons:

1. Redundancy is eliminated. It is wise to adhere to the [**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself (A.K.A. 'DRY') principle](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/). Not only are the calls to `strpos()` redundant, they appear to be identical within the two files. If you really needed such functionality in multiple files, it might be good to abstract it into a function, perhaps in an included file, and call that function. That way modifications can be done in one place instead of every place the functionality is needed.
2. While most user agents tend to have the browser name first and then the platform, if the platform happened to be at the start of the string - e.g. "`Blackberry Mozilla/5.0...`" then [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) would yield `0`, which evaluates to `false`. Note [the warning on the PHP documentation for `strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues):

   > **Warning** This function may return Boolean **FALSE**, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on [Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use [the === operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

I also wanted to point out that the `== true` on these lines:

> ```
> if($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $ipad == true)
> ```

only applies to `$ipad` and not all of the variables combined via the OR operators. You probably know this but one could omit the `== true`, since anything that doesn't evaluate to a boolean **`FALSE`** will be considered **`TRUE`**<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)</sup>.

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting</sub>